# Keeping state when Navigating back and forth with Navigator?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a Widget with a ListView that i navigate to often with `Navigator.push()`. I'm trying to preserve the scrolling with a Key (PageStorageKey/UniqueKey/GlobalKey) with no luck whatsoever.

https://gist.github.com/JellyO1/dd8b50a5bcf2e5c10d7a4047427943c8

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're trying to save the state of scroll when popping the top screen on the stack. You can achieve this in a few ways, but could simply be done by providing the initial offset and saving it back on the context pop by using a custom `ScrollController`. Here's your edited example.

[image: example]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double scrollOffset = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          scrollOffset = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Scrollable(
                    scrollOffset: scrollOffset,
                  )));
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Scrollable extends StatefulWidget {
  final double scrollOffset;
  @override
  State createState() {
    return _ScrollableState();
  }

  Scrollable({this.scrollOffset, Key key}) : super(key: key);
}

class _ScrollableState extends State<Scrollable> {
  ScrollController myScrollController;
  List<Widget> list = List.generate(500, (index) => Text('$index'));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myScrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: widget.scrollOffset);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(myScrollController.offset),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        controller: myScrollController,
        children: list,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, I'm also interested to know if it's possible to make it even more simple by using a `PageStorageKey`.

**Note:** Don't forget to override the back button in Android devices with `WillPopScope` widget if needed, to save the offset as well.

Comment: This works if you have only one Page, in my case i have a listview that is probably infinite and each item has a details page that has a scrollable child. If i was to take this approach i'd have to save every scroll offset manually. Is this viable or do you think it's too expensive?